# Yii2 tagging 2amigos is not saving tags to the table

Tags: php, yii2

I am trying to implement tagged articles for my new small CMS written with yii2.

This is what i have tried https://forum.yiiframework.com/t/how-to-create-tags-for-posts-in-yii2/123890

Everything is working the tagging machanism is fetching data from the tag table but it is not saving data to the table tag_assign.

This is my form.

```
<?php

use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\widgets\ActiveForm;
//Using for Wysiwig editor
use dosamigos\ckeditor\CKEditor;
//Using for Tagging
use dosamigos\selectize\SelectizeTextInput;

/* @var $this yii\web\View */
/* @var $model common\models\Articles */
/* @var $form yii\widgets\ActiveForm */
?>

<div class="articles-form">
    <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'title')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'content')->widget(CKEditor::className(), [
        'options' => ['height' => 800],
        'preset' => 'basic',
        'clientOptions' => ['height' => 400]
    ]) ?>


    <?= $form->field($model, 'tags')->widget(SelectizeTextInput::className(), [
    // calls an action that returns a JSON object with matched
    // tags
      'loadUrl' => ['tag/list'],
      'options' => ['class' => 'form-control'],
      'clientOptions' => [
          'plugins' => ['remove_button'],
          'valueField' => 'name',
          'labelField' => 'name',
          'searchField' => ['name'],
          'create' => true,
      ],
    ])->hint('Use commas to separate tags') ?>


    <?= $form->field($model, 'date')->textInput() ?>

    <div class="form-group">
        <?= Html::submitButton('Save', ['class' => 'btn btn-success']) ?>
    </div>

    <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>

</div>
```

And this is my tag model

```
<?php

namespace common\models;

use Yii;
use dosamigos\taggable\Taggable;
/**
 * This is the model class for table "tags".
 *
 * @property int $id
 * @property string $frequency
 * @property string $name
 */
class Tag extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public static function tableName()
    {
        return 'tags';
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['frequency', 'name'], 'required'],
            [['frequency'], 'string', 'max' => 500],
            [['name'], 'string', 'max' => 250],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return [
            'id' => 'ID',
            'frequency' => 'Frequency',
            'name' => 'Name',
        ];
    }

    //For Tagging
    public function behaviors() {
        return [
            [
                'class' => Taggable::className(),
            ],
        ];
    }
    public function findAllByName($name)
    {
        return Tag::find()->where('name LIKE :query')
                          ->addParams([':query'=>"%$name%"])
                          ->all();
    }
}
```

Tag controller.

```
<?php

namespace backend\controllers;

use Yii;
use common\models\Tag;
use common\models\searchTag;
use yii\web\Controller;
use yii\web\NotFoundHttpException;
use yii\filters\VerbFilter;
use yii\web\Response;

/**
 * TagController implements the CRUD actions for Tag model.
 */
class TagController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function behaviors()
    {
        return [
            'verbs' => [
                'class' => VerbFilter::className(),
                'actions' => [
                    'delete' => ['POST'],
                ],
            ],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Lists all Tag models.
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function actionIndex()
    {
        $searchModel = new searchTag();
        $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);

        return $this->render('index', [
            'searchModel' => $searchModel,
            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Displays a single Tag model.
     * @param integer $id
     * @return mixed
     * @throws NotFoundHttpException if the model cannot be found
     */
    public function actionView($id)
    {
        return $this->render('view', [
            'model' => $this->findModel($id),
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Creates a new Tag model.
     * If creation is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'view' page.
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function actionCreate()
    {
        $model = new Tag();

        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
            return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
        }

        return $this->render('create', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }
    public function actionList($query)
    {
        $models = Tag::findAllByName($query);
        $items = [];

        foreach ($models as $model) {
            $items[] = ['name' => $model->name];
        }
        // We know we can use ContentNegotiator filter
        // this way is easier to show you here :)
        Yii::$app->response->format = Response::FORMAT_JSON;

        return $items;
    }

    /**
     * Updates an existing Tag model.
     * If update is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'view' page.
     * @param integer $id
     * @return mixed
     * @throws NotFoundHttpException if the model cannot be found
     */
    public function actionUpdate($id)
    {
        $model = $this->findModel($id);

        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
            return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
        }

        return $this->render('update', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Deletes an existing Tag model.
     * If deletion is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'index' page.
     * @param integer $id
     * @return mixed
     * @throws NotFoundHttpException if the model cannot be found
     */
    public function actionDelete($id)
    {
        $this->findModel($id)->delete();

        return $this->redirect(['index']);
    }

    /**
     * Finds the Tag model based on its primary key value.
     * If the model is not found, a 404 HTTP exception will be thrown.
     * @param integer $id
     * @return Tag the loaded model
     * @throws NotFoundHttpException if the model cannot be found
     */
    protected function findModel($id)
    {
        if (($model = Tag::findOne($id)) !== null) {
            return $model;
        }

        throw new NotFoundHttpException('The requested page does not exist.');
    }
}
```

And the articles

```
<?php

namespace common\models;

use Yii;
//For Taggable
use dosamigos\taggable\Taggable;
/**
 * This is the model class for table "articles".
 *
 * @property int $id
 * @property string $title
 * @property string $content
 * @property string $tags
 * @property string $date
 */
class Articles extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
    //For taggable
    public function behaviors() {
       return [
           [
               'class' => Taggable::className(),
           ],
       ];
   }
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public static function tableName()
    {
        return 'articles';
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['title', 'content', 'tags', 'date'], 'required'],
            [['content'], 'string'],
            [['date'], 'safe'],
            [['title', 'tags'], 'string', 'max' => 250],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return [
            'id' => 'ID',
            'title' => 'Title',
            'content' => 'Content',
            'tags' => 'Tags',
            'date' => 'Date',
        ];
    }
    public function getTags()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Tag::className(), ['id' => 'tag_id'])->viaTable('tag_assign', ['article_id' => 'id']);
    }

}
```

What I am missing? How can I trouble shoot at least what is going wrong?

Comment: Did you attached `Taggable` behavior to  `Articles` model?

Comment: @rob006 I have updated the code,Its still not working :(

Comment: Do you have model tag_assign?